# Spring Logging is added to System.out but not file (log4j)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j

I'm using Spring Boot with log4j. My problem is that my appender have different outputs, although they have almost the same configuration.

My config:

```
log4j.rootCategory=ALL, stdout, logfile
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=\r%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=imagesearch.log
log4j.appender.logfile.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.logfile.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

The problem is that the console appender includes the Spring logging, but the FileAppender doesn't, but I need the Spring logging also in my file.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, try to change from

```
log4j.rootCategory=ALL, stdout, logfile
```

to

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout, logfile
```

as RootCategory is deprecated
[log4j documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/RootCategory.html)

Comment: thanks for advise, but that wasn't it, I somewhere heard that it has something to do with Spring which only sends it logs to the system.out, but I can't find it in the big web.